# Can two persons with same flight ticket apply for visa from different countries?

Tags: visas, malaysia

My friend and I are going to visit Malaysia. I live in Germany and my friend lives in India. We have booked a common flight  ticket from Delhi, India to Malaysia.

**QUESTION:** Is it possible that I apply for Malaysian visa from Germany and my friend apply from India?

**UPDATE:** Thanks for funny, sarcastic and meaningful replies. I just meant that we (my friend and I) have a single booking (a ticket on which my friend's name and my name are written). So, I was wondering could it be a problem if I submit this ticket for the visa. I was just curious if the embassy could ask me the details of the second person. Apparently, it should not be any problem.

Comment: Do you have any evidence suggesting that it would cause a problem?

Comment: @pnuts It's when two people hide in a single suit,  trying to pass as an extremely overweight man.

Comment: I'm wondering what alternative the OP has in mind.

Comment: German nationals do not need a visa for Malaysia for a stay for less than 90 days: http://www.kln.gov.my/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=225808&folderId=231025&name=DLFE-1922.pdf

Comment: I understand that basic questions are fine on SE but this seems to only be a small step above "should two people each brush their own teeth?".

Comment: There can be a couple of _hundred_ people on the same flight, from a lot of different countries. The fact that you have met one of them before does not change your individual visa requirements.

Comment: @oerkelens I think OP is talking about it being a single booking. (Not that that changes anything, but just saying.)

Comment: I've rolled back an edit that invalidated the wording of current answers.

Comment: @AntonSherwood You mean why OP would consider applying from India instead of Germany? Many possibilities. For example, maybe they are going to India tomorrow and don't have time to apply in Germany before they leave. Or maybe they are going to stay in India for so long that a visa obtained in Germany before departure would expire by the time they went to Malaysia (some countries have visas that start on the date of issue.) However, all this does seem unlikely as OP seems to want to apply in Germany.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which country your travel companion applies from is irrelevant to which country *you* should apply from.

> Can two persons with same flight ticket apply for visa from different
>   countries?

Yes. Actually, it's generally *preferable* to apply from your *country of residence.* For many countries,  it's even a *strict requirement*.  (Edit: and the Malaysian embassy in India appears to be an example of it,  as @phoog's answer now shows.) Both of you should *apply in your respective countries of residence*.

If you were thinking of applying in India, one of the only situations in which you might be able to do so is if you are an Indian citizen. But even then, you probably would still want to apply from your country of residence. It's less complicated and you avoid the [complications described by mcenzm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77716/41775).

Comment: What's more, many countries *require* application in the place of residence.

Answer (score 22):

It's not only possible, it is required.

Malaysia's consulates in both the India and Germany require visa applicants to prove that they reside in their respective countries.

From the VFS pages for Malaysian visa applications in India:

> Foreign National’s [sic] will have to submit a valid address proof of India.

(Source: http://www.vfsglobal.com/malaysia/india/wrf_documentsrequired.html)

The Malaysian consulate general in Frankfurt notes among the required documents for a visa application:

> Valid Residence permit for Germany

(Source: http://www.kln.gov.my/web/deu_frankfurt/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/application-for-visa-to-malaysia?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fdeu_frankfurt%2Fother_information)

Answer (score 4):

When you are flying with the airline I am working for in IT, as an example, you are technically getting multiple tickets even if you have booked the flight together.
The distinction of bookings (reservation data like seats) and tickets (mostly commercial data such as fares and fees) is mostly for technical reasons and dates back to ancient technology.
All of this has no relevance for visa and other "official" documents.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can apply that way.

Actually we do submit our tickets (photocopy) when we apply for visas.

However, it isn't a strict neccesity. We do it that way in order to provide some proof of our planned journey. That's it. You dont need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Not only required at Country Level, but possibly at provincial level as well for India. This especially applies to PRC. I'm in Australia and I have to apply independently of my wife because we officially reside in different states. Try and follow the South, West, Southwest, and "Mumbai, Ahmedabad & Pune" requirements for Malaysia in @phoogs link above....